# Tags in JSP Page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, jstl

I am trying to understand an existing Spring MVC application, in a JSP page I found the below code

```
<c:forEach items="${responseData}" var="data">
            <li>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${data.firstName}">
                        <span class="strike">
                        ${f:h(data.lastName)}
                        </span>
                    </c:when>

                    <c:otherwise>
                    Somem JSP code
```

Here I can't understand the meaning of code  `${f:h(data.lastName)}`, even If I remove `f:h`, means I use `${(data.lastName)}` instead of `${f:h(data.lastName)}`, then it gives me same result, then what is the use of `f:h` and what it stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code uses JSEL tag library.

[Java Standard EL Functions](http://amateras.osdn.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=JSEL)

> Java Standard EL Functions(JSEL) provides standard EL functions for web application development.

Your jsp page must have following line, to include the taglib:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://amateras.sf.jp/functions" prefix="f" %>
```

If you go through description of functions offered by JSEL, function `f:h(String value)` is used to ***Escape HTML tags***.

**$** is syntax for using **JSP EL**.

So, the difference between code ${f:h(data.lastName)} and ${(data.lastName)} is, ${f:h(data.lastName)} is just escaping any HTML content in the string.

Just try to print HTML tag say `<p>example<p>` on your page. With ${f:h(data.lastName)}, you will be able to view `<p>example<p>` text on your page. However, if you use ${(data.lastName)}, you will just be able to see `example` text on your page, as this time HTML tags are not escaped.

Comment: Hi @Sudharshan_SMD , thanks for your concern, but i can't find anything like <%@ taglib uri="http://amateras.sf.jp/functions" prefix="f" %> in my workspace, even I did't find any HTML tag while using  ${f:h(data.lastName)}

Comment: There has to be tag library included somewhere on your page. Are your using tiles? Try 'view source' on your rendered jsp page, you should be able to find taglib.

Comment: <taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">      This tag is being used in my f.tld file

Comment: Sudarshan thanks . I got it f is my own library and h is a function inside this library